# underline in a part of a section title in amsart

Tags: sectioning, text-decorations, amsart

I want to use math symbols including underline (e.g. `$\underline{R}_{H,V}$`) in a section title in a document in `amsart` documentclass with table of contents.  So I typed (roughly)

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{The functor ${\underline{R}}_{H,V}$}

\end{document}
```

If I compile this file, I get the section title as wanted, but without the underline in the table of contents.  If I compile once more, I get the following error message:

```
Missing } inserted
            }
...elax }_{H,V}$
```

I checked this site and found advices suggesting to use `sectsty` or `titlesec` packages.  But they seem to be useful only when you want to underline the whole section title in article documentclass.  Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since `\section` has a "floating" argument, what i'd try first is `\protect\underline`.

absence of `\protect` is a very frequent cause of the `missing }` error for chapter and section titles and captions, and not just with ams document classes.

Comment: Wow, \proctect command solved the problem.  Thank you very much!